# how to install texttable in python

Tags: python, freetexttable

My code is:

```
import texttable as tt  
tab = tt.TextTable()  
header = ['Manager', 'Club', 'Year']  
tab.header(header)  
print tab.draw()
```

During execution the following error occurs.

ImportError: No module named texttable

Can anyone help me with the steps to install texttable or with other solutions.

Comment: You need to install texttable via pip (something like `pip install texttable` should do it). As a sidenote, you should try using virtual environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download the module from the [python website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/texttable).

Decompress the archive, and go into the directory. Then execute the script `setup.py` with `install` in argument:

```
python setup.py install
```

You can find more information in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/install/).

Comment: It is not a reason to downvote him. The user can see a warning on the shell asking him superuser permissions anyway. And even on the official official Linux documentation, we frequently find commands without `sudo` because it is implicit anyway. @user3251664

Answer (score 1):

1. Download `pip` from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.5.2.tar.gz
2. Unzip the contents to any `<dir>`
3. `cd <dir>`
4. `python setup.py install`
5. Install texttable calling `pip install texttable`

Answer (score 0):

I have installed texttable with python3.

I ran your code and received the same error!

I changed this -->>`tab = tt.TextTable()` to this -->> `tab = tt.Texttable()`

note the lower case 't' and all went well.

Hope this helps

p.s. *I have just realised that this reply is in 2020 and your question was in 2014. You are now probably much older and the CEO of a huge Blue Chip company!!!
Sorry I'm late :¬)*